# Pandas add two data frames by common variable

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes A, B which have the same column names;

```
["x","0","1","2"]
```

of which I wish to add the numeric columns `["0","1","2"]` together by the string column`"x"`. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you add some sample data and desired output? 3,4 rows.

Comment: Or do you need `pd.merge(A, B, on='x')` ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set the common index and then sum all columns:

```
pd.merge(A, B, on = ['x']).set_index(['x']).sum(axis=1)
```